# Boxplot with automatic quartiles - how to fit more than 4 plots?

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I ran into the following problem: I want to use `/pgfplots/boxplot` to calculate and display the quartiles (and whiskers) using raw data. So instead of using `boxplot prepare` I would like to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y,width=1.0\textwidth]
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\ 0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 1.0\\
0.7\\ 1.0\\ 0.9\\ 0.8\\ 0.9\\ 0.9\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\ 0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 1.0\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\  0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 0.6\\
};
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\ 0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 0.0\\
0.7\\ 1.0\\ 0.9\\ 0.8\\ 0.0\\ 0.4\\
};
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.4\\ 0.4\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 1.0\\
0.7\\ 1.0\\ 0.9\\ 0.8\\ 0.9\\ 0.99\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\  0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 0.6\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But then there is a problem: after compilation I see only four plots instead of six (image below) - how to fix this?
[image: results of executing the above code]

Comment: Please make your included sample compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it is only plotting 4 of the 6 you want it to is because you've only told it to plot 4 of them. If you put `\addplot+[boxplot]` before all 6 of the datasets, it plots all 6 correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y,width=1.0\textwidth]
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\ 0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 1.0\\
0.7\\ 1.0\\ 0.9\\ 0.8\\ 0.9\\ 0.9\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\ 0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 1.0\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\  0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 0.6\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\ 0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 0.0\\
0.7\\ 1.0\\ 0.9\\ 0.8\\ 0.0\\ 0.4\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.4\\ 0.4\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 1.0\\
0.7\\ 1.0\\ 0.9\\ 0.8\\ 0.9\\ 0.99\\
};
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
0.1\\ 0.2\\  0.1\\ 0.5\\ 0.4\\ 0.6\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{picture}
\caption{Sample box plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```